# Issue: iteration in sh

Tags: bash, sh

I'm kind new in sh and I would like to make iteration on an array.

```
declare -a NumPack
NumPack=(88 88 454 454 65 874 874 21 21)
for carton in $NumPack
do
echo "carton: $NumPack"
done
```

I would like to search for the same numbers like the first one.
My program would return 2 for the first number(88), 3 for the next number(454), 1 for the next (65).

I also have a second array with the numbers of articles which contain those pack above.

```
declare -a NumArt
NumArt= (ZZZZ CCDE AZDSDS SDSEE AAAZE TTGYH DFDF ARFFF TRUCC TOUCKC)
```

the articles

```
(ZZZZ,CCDE) belong to the pack 88 
the articles (AZDSDS,SDSE,AAAZE) belong to the pack 454, 
the article TTGYH belong to the pack 65, 
the articles (DFDF,ARFFF) belong to 874, and the rest to 21.
```

I had to push those lines in a files by pair of 4. I had to avoid to split a pack. Every articles belong to a pack must be in a one file.

So the

```
88 => file1
  454,65 => file2
  (874,21) =>file3.
```

thanks for your help

Comment: If your objective is to solve the problem, use the `uniq -c` command. If your objective is to learn shell script, use an associative array (`declare -A`) -- it works the same as a `map`, `dictionary` or `hashtable` in other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are wanting to learn rather than solve the problem (in which case I'd advocate the use of the `uniq -c` command)

See the following script:

```
declare -a NumPack
NumPack=(88 88 454 454 65 874 874 21 21)
declare -A res
for carton in "${NumPack[@]}"
do
echo "carton: $carton"
res[$carton]=$((${res[$carton]}+1))
done
echo ${res[@]}
```

I create an associative array named `res` to hold the result. Note the proper way to iterate: `for carton in ${NumPack[@]}` and the use of `$(( ))` for algebraic expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @damienfrançois. This is very helpful. But My larger than that. I assume according to your name you are french tongue. Can I continue in french

Comment: +1. This is the right solution with bash. I suggest quoting your multi-element expansions to prevent word splitting: `"${NumPack[@]}"`, `"${res[@]}"`

Comment: Also I think `res[$carton]=$((${res[$carton]}+1))` can simply be just `(( ++res[$carton] ))`.

Comment: @user3438349 Your bash needs to be version 4.0 or newer. Try showing us the output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`.

Comment: Well that's 3.2. Any chance that you can upgrade it to a newer version?

Comment: when I tried with a lower a it works. In fact I have 2 arrays. One with the articles and the one with their pack. I would like to retain to push some pack in a file and the other one in other file. My file can contain only 4 articles. I have the 88 in one file, the 454 and the 65 in a second file, the 874 and the 21 in other file.

Comment: Cannot upgrade for a newer version

Comment: Hello @Damien your solution is working but It kind sort the res array. Is there any solution to prevent this. I'd like 2 3 1 2 2. Thanks again

Comment: @user3438349 with your example my test outputs `2 2 1 2 2` which seems ok? Where would the 3 come from?

Comment: I Test with another set of array,    NumPack=(88 88 454 454 454 65 874 874 21 21)

Comment: Even with my example above, I get     2 1 2 2 2